# Unit Testing - How to structure Firebase mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, firebase, junit, mockito, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unit testing my application using the Mockito framework.

### TL;DR

Should I create a mock for every possible result of a class and set their behaviours in the @Before or should I create just one mock for every class and then define their behaviours in each test that uses them?

### Context

Right now I'm testing the `DataRepository`, that has `getPosts(String postId)`. `DataRepository` receives a `FirebaseFirestore` instance via DI.

`getPosts` returns a `Maybe<List<Post>>` with the following code:

```
fun getPosts(companyId: String): Maybe<List<Post>> {
    return Maybe.create { emitter ->
        firestore.collection("companies/$companyId/posts").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        if (it.result.isEmpty) {
                            emitter.onComplete()
                        } else {
                            emitter.onSuccess(it.result.toObjects(Post::class.java))
                        }
                    } else {
                        emitter.onError(it.exception ?: UnknownError())
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

### Problem

To test this function and the various cases (success/empty/failed) I have to mock FirebaseFirestore, then the CollectionReference, then the Task, then the OnCompleteListener (with an argument captor) and so on. Basically everything.

### Question

When I mock the task should I

a. Create a `successfulTaskMock` that I set in the @Before to always be successful and one for the failure? Same thing with a valid/empty `validQuerySnapshot`/`emptyQuerySnapshot`?

b. Create only a `taskMock` and then change its return value directly inside the test? (Make taskMock.isSuccessful return true in the success test and false in the failure test)

I've looked at some GitHub repos: some do a., some do b.

Problem with a. is I would end up with tons of mocks for the same class, but with very clean and readable tests.

Problem with b. is I should setup each mock at the start of every test, thus having a lot of boilerplate code.

### Conclusion

I've read that I could use deep mocking to only create the end result of a call (the QuerySnapshot, as opposed to Firestore + Collection + Task etc.) but that seems to be very frowned upon and I can see why.

Maybe there is even a third way that I don't know of. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.